# Quelle est l’expression diamétralement opposée à « encore moins » ?

Tags: expressions

> Négative : Je ne m’intéresse pas à tes idéaux, **encore moins** à ton sort.

Comme « encore moins » ne s’emploie que dans une phrase négative, il faut y substituer une autre expression dans la phrase affirmative suivante, même si le sens des deux versions revient foncièrement au même. J’hésite entre « et plus encore » et « et encore plus ».

> Affirmative : Je me moque de tes idéaux **et plus encore** de ton sort. {ou : **et encore plus**}

Comment: Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait une différence entre les deux. De la même manière *moins encore* fonctionnerait dans le premier exemple, non ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les deux fonctionnent en soi.

*Et plus encore* me semble être beaucoup plus soutenu que *et encore plus*. C'est là toute la différence que je vois.

Voilà un autre exemple :

> Je me moque de tes idéaux et beaucoup plus de ton sort.

C'est l'utilisation du mot *plus* qui importe.

Comment: On peut même dire "bien plus (encore)"

Comment: Je me demande s’il en va de même pour « encore moins à » et « moins encore à ». Appartiennent-ils à différents registres ? Merci.

Comment: Plutôt, oui. "Moins encore" me semble être une forme soutenue de "encore moins" (qui est utilisé tous les jours). "Moins encore" s'entend peu dans un échange (épistolaire ou non) courant.

Comment: @MorganFR Hi. Do you mean: "Je me moque de tes idéaux et bien plus de ton sort."?

Comment: @Ahalone-zee That's exactly what he meant, the "encore" would be adding even more strength to the sentence.

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean, and you can even add "encore" after "plus" for extra effect. "plus" is (as @Shozs said) the important word. you can add extra words before and after like "encore" and "bien/beaucoup" for more effect. Most of those words can be inverted aswell (bien plus encore -> encore bien plus).

Comment: J'y vois une autre différence. "Et plus encore", est plein de sous-entendus, et pas "encore plus". Par exemple. "C'est une amie, et plus encore" a clairement un sous-entendu à connotation amoureuse ou sexuelle, mais "C'est une amie, et encore plus" laisse penser que c'est juste une amie en or,  sans penser à autre(s) chose(s) qu'à l'amitié.

Comment: @Ah alone-zee. Tu n'aurais pas "moins encore à". Tu aurais: et moins encore (mais ce n'est pas du tout une expression répandue comme l'est "et plus encore", il n'y a pas les mêmes connotations), et encore moins=serait la façon courante de le dire, mais tout dépend de la phrase.